# C++ - Multiple enum delcarations in a program

Tags: c++, enums, namespaces, header-files

Is it bad form to put a namespace declaration in a .h file?

```
//object.h
namespace Stuff {
 enum Type {Player, Enemy, Gold, Potion}
}
...
```

When other files include object.h, it may end up being defined more than once. Would that be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is why you would include header guards (pragma once, if / end if). You can also use the enum *class* type, e.g. enum class EnumClassName for scope resolution instead of a namespace.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you haven't included HEADER GUARD in the .h file.
It would look like this -

```
#ifndef _HEADER_GUARD_
#define _HEADER_GUARD_

//Your .h file content

#endif
```

This prevents the multiple inclusion of the same header file in a file.
People usually use the name of the .h file as HEADER_GUARD macros.

Like, for a file named abhi.h, i prefer to use _ABHI_H_